# How to get a each product id in category page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, category

How to get a each product id in category page? I need to get the product id in custom module template file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i need a all product id separately

Comment: Hey @divyasekar did you get id?

Comment: In which block you want to get product id?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create plugin for that. For that follow below steps :

Add plugin in your **di.xml** file :

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="block-product-list" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\ProductList" sortOrder="10" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Then, Create plugin file.

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/ProductList.php

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin;

class ProductList {

    public function afterGetProductDetailsHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
        $result,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    ) {
        return $result . $product->getId();
    }
}
```

You will get product id after product price in listing page.

Answer (score 2):

Add this two files in your **Vendorename_Modulename**

we overrite defult category view page

**app/code/Vendorename/Modulename/view/frontend/layout**

***catalog_category_view.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <container name="category.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="category-view" after="-">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.image" template="Magento_Catalog::category/image.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description" template="Magento_Catalog::category/description.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.cms" template="Magento_Catalog::category/cms.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Vendorename_Modulename::list.phtml">
                    <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                               name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                    </action>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="compareProductLink" xsi:type="string">.action.tocompare</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">page-title-heading</argument>
                <argument name="add_base_attribute_aria" xsi:type="string">page-title-heading toolbar-amount</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\Rss\Link" name="rss.link" template="Magento_Catalog::category/rss.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

here we are modifying this phtml file

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Vendorename_Modulename::list.phtml">
```

now add product list for show product id in every product

**app/code/Vendorename/Modulename/view/frontend/templates**

***list.phtml***

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

?>
<?php

/**
 * Product list template
 *
 */
?>
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class);
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()) :?>
    <div class="message info empty"><div><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('We can\'t find products matching the selection.')) ?></div></div>
<?php else :?>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?= $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php
    if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
    /**
     * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
     */
    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <div class="products wrapper <?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?> products-<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?>">
        <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) :?>
            <li class="item product product-item">
                <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?>">
                    <?php
                    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $imageDisplayArea);
                    if ($pos != null) {
                        $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                            . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php // Product Image ?>
                    <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                       class="product photo product-item-photo"
                       tabindex="-1">
                        <?= $productImage->toHtml() ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <?php
                            $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                        ?>
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                            <a class="product-item-link"
                               href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>">
                                <?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                                Product ID: <?= /* @noEscape */ $_product->getId() ?>
                        </strong>
                        <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()) :?>
                            <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <div class="product-item-inner">
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $block->escapeHtmlAttr($position) : '' ?>>
                                <div class="actions-primary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $block->escapeHtmlAttr($position) : '' ?>>
                                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) :?>
                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form"
                                              data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_product->getSku()) ?>"
                                              action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($postParams['action']) ?>"
                                              method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                   name="product"
                                                   value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="<?= /* @noEscape */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>"
                                                   value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
                                            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                            <button type="submit"
                                                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                    class="action tocart primary">
                                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    <?php else :?>
                                        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()) :?>
                                            <div class="stock available"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span></div>
                                        <?php else :?>
                                            <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $block->escapeHtmlAttr($position) : '' ?>>
                                    <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')) :?>
                                        <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php if ($showDescription) :?>
                                <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                    <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                                       title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                       class="action more"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Learn More')) ?></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) :?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {
                    "product_sku": "<?= $block->escapeJs($_product->getSku()) ?>"
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

in above .phtml file we add product id.

Screenshot are give below

[image]

Comment: We should not override when output will get proper by plugin or observer.

Comment: @RohanHapani please see screenshot. And we can override file many way. it's dependent on requirements.

Comment: Please read my comment again. I'm just told u about if output will be same by override and plugin then, always use plugin instead of override whole file.

Comment: @RohanHapani Thanks for this useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Add the below code to your block

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;
class ProductCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
  protected $_productCollectionFactory;   
  public function __construct(
     \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
     \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory 
      $productCollectionFactory,        
      array $data = []
 )
  {    
      $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
      parent::__construct($context, $data);
  } 
  public function getProductCollection()
  {
      $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
      $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
      return $collection;
  }
}
```

on your template file add the below code to get all the product ids

```
$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
  echo $product->getId();     
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using a above code i get a product id like this  https://prnt.sc/ng2pb3

Comment: You want to show it with the product in the sense you gotta edit list page phtml and get the id like $_product->getId();  from the there

Comment: I tried that way but I cannot pass a product id from theme to my custom module @Prathap

Comment: As of my understanding you can extend the phtml to your theme then you do like this and am not clear what do you mean custom module in order to achieve this. Please update us the complete requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the product id in the product listing template file, then you can try following code

```
$_product->getId()
```

Comment: i need product id in custom module  template file not  in theme

Comment: @divyasekar How are you showing/fetching the products? Share that code.

Comment: Anush I m asking about that only how to fetch each product id

Comment: Using @prathap answer i get a product id like this https://prnt.sc/ng2pb3

Comment: @divyasekar Kindly share your code.

Comment: Wait i will post a code