# How to display text in this place?

Tags: magento2

I want to display one massage on everithing item.
Which reference Container name?

[image]

Comment: Is this category page or something else?

Comment: Please try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/303469

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add some text just after product name on list page.
so you need to override below core file in your theme and add message as per you want.

`module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After logging into the admin, Go to Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enable Template Path Hints for Storefront and change the text whatever you want.